# How many normal subgroups of the free group on $n$ generators?

Tags: group-theory, elementary-set-theory

Let $F_n$ be a free group on $n>1$ elements and $\mathcal{N}(F_n)$ the set of normal subgroups of $F_n$. Since there are uncountably many nonisomorphic groups on two generators we have that $\mathcal{N}(F_n)$ is uncountable. Also, it is easy to see that the cardinality is less than or equal to the cardinality of the reals.

> Can the cardinality of $\mathcal{N}(F_n)$ not equal the cardinality of the reals? (ZFC)
>
> For $m>n$, can we have that $|\mathcal{N}(F_m)|>|\mathcal{N}(F_n)|$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is proven in

R. Grigorchuk, 
Degrees of growth of finitely generated groups, and the theory of invariant
means. Math. USSR, Izv. 25, (1985) p. 259-300

that there is a continuum of pairwise nonisomorphic 2-generated periodic groups of intermediate growth (Theorem A of the paper). Therefore, it follows that ${\mathcal N}(F_n)$ has cardinality of continuum for all $n\ge 2$.

Comment: See also B. H. Neumann, *Some remarks on infinite groups*, J. London Math. Soc. 12 (1937) 120-127, where he proves that there is a continuum of pairwise $2$-generated groups.

Comment: @user1729: Thanks, good to know!